# scala xml EntityResolver equivilent

Tags: xml, scala

I've been trying to get scala's xml parsing to allow me to set an EntityResolver.

I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find substantial documentation. What's the correct way of pointing scala's parser to the correct location for a dtd file?

```
object MyXML {
  def loadFile(file: File): Node = {

    println("loadFile called")

    val parser: SAXParser = scala.xml.XML.parser
    parser.getParser.setEntityResolver(new MyXMLEntityResolver)
    // Also tried: parser.getXMLReader.setEntityResolver...    

    val inputSource = new InputSource(file.getAbsolutePath)

    val loader = scala.xml.XML.withSAXParser(parser)


    loader.loadFile(file)

    //scala.xml.XML.loadXML(inputSource, parser)
  }

  class MyXMLEntityResolver extends EntityResolver {
    override def resolveEntity(publicId: String, systemId: String): InputSource = {

      println("Resolve called!")

      new InputSource(systemId)

    }
  }
}

// prints only "loadFile called"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the important thing to override is the `adapter` method in `XMLLoader[T]` with an adapter that does the correct resolving, rather than setting `EntityResolver` of the `parser` method (even overriding it does not work!)

So, I have a class like this, which seems to solve it

```
class MyXMLParser extends XMLLoader[Elem] {
 override def adapter = {
   new MyXMLAdapter
  }
}

class PhysicsXMLAdapter extends NoBindingFactoryAdapter {
  val myEntityResolver = new MyEntityResolver
  override def resolveEntity(publicId: String, systemId: String): InputSource = {
     myEntityResolver.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId)
  }
}
```